# Is there anything wrong in this CFG Bison definition?

Tags: grammar, bison, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I have the following grammar in a Bison file:

```
lst: ID COMMA lst
   | ID
   | /*empty*/

plst: lst SEMICOLON lst
    | SEMICOLON lst
    | lst
```

WHere the first rule actually tries to map a list of identifiers like `id1,id2,id3...`

And the second wants to map a posible couple of lists separated by a semicolon. Allowed possibilities are: `id11,id12,id13...;id21,id22,id23...`, `id1,id2,id3...` or `;id1,id2,id3...`.

I was wondering if this is a correct set of rules as Bison is returning many conflicts. I thought one of possible problems might be not well formed rules. So my question is: the aforementioned set of rules, is a good one or it is coflict-prone? Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you allow `lst` to be empty. So there is no way to distinguish between:

```
lst ';' lst
```

and

```
';' lst
```

In other words, is the `lst` empty or absent? The grammar is ambiguous.

I'd remove the empty production for `lst`, but there are other solutions.